# How to update json column in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I have a `json` column in my `Categories` table and I want to update each category record with a translation from a json file. I have built the json file so that it contains a categories array and each category has a name and a translation, like so:

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
        "name": "starter",
        "message": "Abs/Анти блокираща система (система против боксуване)"
    },
    {
        "name": "alternator",
        "message": "Алтернатор"
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

I want every category record to be updated with the language key as well as the translation from the file, like so:

`{ bg: 'translation from file' }`

I have this code

```
file = File.read('app/services/translations/files/bg.json')
data = JSON.parse(file)
language = File.basename(file, '.json')
Translations::CategoriesMigrator.call(file: data, language: language)

module Translations
  class CategoriesMigrator < Service
    def initialize(category_repo: Category)
      @category_repo = category_repo
    end

    def call(file:, language:)
      file['categories'].each do |category|
        found_category = @category_repo.find_by(name: category['name'])
        found_category.translated_categories[language] = category['message']
        found_category.save
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Right now I end up having all categories in a single category record. What am I doing wrong?

#### Update

My db migration looks like this:

```
class AddTranslatedCategoriesToCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :categories, :translated_categories, :jsonb, null: false, default: {}
    add_index :categories, :translated_categories, using: :gin
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you using PosgreSQL right? What version? And what Rails version?

Comment: Yeah, Postgres, Rails 5.1.7

Comment: What's the structure of the data stored in that JSON column? How does the migration of that table look like?

Comment: @SebastianPalma I've just added the migration definition to my question.

Comment: Nevermind, I had an error in `language = File.basename(file, '.json')`. File.basename expects a file path, not the file itself. Sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry to play the devils advocate but why not just add the translations to a separate table? Its going to be far easier to query. This seems like yet another case where you should just use the relational model properly.

Comment: I need to be able to display the translation on the frontend which I built using React so I just thought to store it in a json column and then grab proper translation key when the locale changes on button click, like so: category[locale]. Now I am thinking that maybe it wasn't a good idea...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON/JSONB is a good choice when you have data that does not fit in the relational model. In most other cases its an anti-pattern since it makes it much harder to query the data and provides no data integrity or normalization.

This case is definitely the later since the underlaying structure is not dynamic. To keep track of translations we just need to know the subject, the language and the translation.

```
class Category
  has_many :category_translations
end

# rails g model category_translation category:belongs_to locale:string text:string
class CategoryTranslation
  belongs_to :category
end
```

You can add a compound index on category_id and locale to enforce uniqueness.

See:

- https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Comment: Your welcome. I have a feeling that this has been done before and you might be able to find some examples of using the I18n module with a custom backend (your database).